# Calculating the AVG value per GROUP in the GROUP BY Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, group-by, average

I'm working on a query in SQL Server 2005 that looks at a table of recorded phone calls, groups them by the hour of the day, and computes the average wait time for each hour in the day.

I have a query that I think works, but I'm having trouble convincing myself it's right.

```
SELECT
    DATEPART(HOUR, CallTime) AS Hour,
    (AVG(calls.WaitDuration) / 60) AS WaitingTimesInMinutes
FROM (
    SELECT
        CallTime,
        WaitDuration
    FROM Calls
    WHERE DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(Day, 0, CallTime), 0) = DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(Day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
        AND DATEPART(HOUR, CallTime) BETWEEN 6 AND 18
) AS calls
GROUP BY DATEPART(HOUR, CallTime)
ORDER BY DATEPART(HOUR, CallTime);
```

To clarify what I think is happening, this query looks at all calls made on the same day as today, and where the hour of the call is between 6 and 18 -- the times are recorded and SELECTed in 24-hour time, so this between hours is to get calls between 6am and 6pm.

Then, the outer query computes the average of the WaitDuration column (and converts seconds to minutes) and then groups each average by the hour.

What I'm uncertain of is this: Are the reported BY HOUR averages only for the calls made in that hour's timeframe? Or does it compute each reported average using all the calls made on the day and between the hours? I know the AVG function has a optional OVER/PARTITION clause, and it's been a while since I used the AVG group function. What I would like is that each result grouped by an hour shows ONLY the average wait time for that specific hour of the day.

Thanks for your time in this.

Comment: You restriction on hours is actually going to allow calls up to 6:59:59pm. You should probably just say `CallTime BETWEEN <start> and <end>` or at least cut it off at hour 17.

Comment: Oooh, good catch @Shawn! Thanks.

Comment: `CallTime >= dateadd(hour, 6, cast(current_timestamp as date))) and CallTime < dateadd(hour, 18, cast(current_timestamp as date)))`

Comment: I'll go with the first idea, since SQL Server 2005 doesn't have a DATE type. :)

Comment: I couldn't remember if they added in 2005 or 2008. You can always use `{fn current_date()}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grouping happens on the values that get spit out of `datepart(hour, ...)`. You're already filtering on that value so you know they're going to range between 6 and 18. That's all that the grouping is going to see.

Now of course the `datepart()` function does what you're looking for in that it looks at the clock and gives the hour component of the time. If you want your group to coincide with HH:00:00 to HH:59:59.997 then you're in luck.

I've already noted in comments that you probably meant to filter your range from 6 to 17 and that your query will probably perform better if you change that and compare your raw `CallTime` value against a static range instead. Your reasoning looks correct to me. And because your reasoning is correct, you don't need the inner query (derived table) at all.

Also if `WaitDuration` is an integer then you're going to be doing decimal division in your output. You'd need to cast to decimal in that case or change the divisor a decimal value like 60.00.

Comment: I'm marking this as the correct answer because it provided the most information about my query, helping me see how the query is correct. Therefore I think it answered my question the most.

Answer (score 2):

Yes if you use the AVG function with a GROUP BY only the items in that group are averaged.  Just like if you use the COUNT function with a GROUP BY only the items in that group are counted.

You can use windowing functions (OVER/PARTITION) to conceptually perform GROUP BYs on different criteria for a single function.

eg

```
AVG(zed) OVER (PARTITION BY DATEPART(YEAR, CallTime)) as YEAR_AVG
```

Comment: This answer I also found useful and very clear. Thanks @Hogan!

Answer (score 0):

> Are the reported BY HOUR averages only for the calls made in that hour's timeframe?

Yes.  The `WHERE` clause is applied *before* the grouping and aggregation, so the aggregation will apply to all records that fit the `WHERE` clause and within each group.